# Joomla setting custom css for mobile screens only

Tags: css, joomla, responsive-design, joomla-extensions

I have to override the property of a css element when it is viewed on mobile screen. Like there is a logo and it's top margin should be different when on desktop and some other value when on mobile or tablet.

Is it possible. If yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with Media Queries in css.

- Here is a link from where you can get all media quires used for mobile responsive layouts: [Media Queries for Responsive Layouts](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)
- In specific curly brace you have to write the css for elements for which you want changes with mobiles, tablets and other devices.
- Like, as per your question you can change css for logo for mobile, tablets and other desktop screen.

Let me know if it helps you or not.

Thanks, 
Mrunal.